# create loop for, in angular 2 from a template

Tags: typescript, angular

Is possible, use something like the following in a template of angular2,

```
for int a = 0; a < numberTest; a++
```

this numberTest is in code component:

```
numberTest: number = 5;
```

and the template, something like this, it is better to illustrate what I mean:

```
<li *ngFor="#int a = 0; a < numberTest">
```

---

I know that could be solved using an array, and iterate for example:

```
<li *ngFor="#item of items">
```

but my question is, if possible, create a for, in the template, which take the value condition using a variable component, hope I explain well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<li *ngFor="#int of range(numberTest)">
```

with a helper function:

```
let range = (value) => { 
 let a = []; for(let i = 0; i < value; ++i) { a.push(i+1) } return a; }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CNVqxU?p=preview

Comment: his answer is what I wanted, I understand that it is not possible to use without creating an array

Answer (score 3):

NgFor includes an `index` value for exactly this purpose

No function or intermediate state necessary.

```
<ul *ngFor="#item of items; #i = index">
  <li *ngIf="i < numberTest">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

*Source: [Angualar2 Docs - NgFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html)*

*Note: This isn't tested so it may require a little tweaking.*

Comment: The above link is broken. This may help:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html